# No access to registry but local administrator

Tags: windows-8, windows-registry, administrator, regedit

My **domain joined Windows 8 client** will **not** start the `regedit.exe`.

I am local administrator on my machine, means my domain user is in the administrators group.

I know that there are several GPOs applied, but my intention was if I am administrator I can do "everything".

I also tried to start a powershell in admin context (working fine) and type in `regedit` but with no success. Everytime I hit enter a message box appears with the error message, that the administrator has forbidden to edit the registry. *(I know the picture is from W7 but I have not found a picture from W8)*

[image]

Comment: Does you account use *admin* rights or **domain admin** rights?

Comment: just because you are a local admin, I believe GPO can override your user having access to the registry.

Comment: You are not an administrator of the domain thus your unable to perform this operation. You being a local administrator means (almost) nothing if you are part of a domain. The domain permissions trumps the local administrator permissions. Your intention ( which is the wrong word by the way ) is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are joined to a domain there is a level of privilege above Local Administrator called Domain Administrator. Domain Administrators can put restrictions on Local Administrators (via GPOs) that the local administrator himself can not remove (without leaving the domain).

If you need to edit your registry contact the network's IT department and they can push the registry change down to you via a GPO specifically for your username.

There are work arounds you could do, but I am not going to list them as circumventing IT policy will likely get you fired/banned from whatever network you are joined to.